# Netty client clean multipart tmp data

Tags: netty, vertx-httpclient

I'm using VertX http client, which uses netty under hood.
When requests with large parameters are being sent, tmp files are generated in /tmp/ : Attr_[timestamp]_[parameterName].att, for example `Attr_456456132456431_username.att` (which is, for example, 80 KB size)

Requests work fine, but that files are never deleted. It can be done by hand, but I'm looking for a proper solution. Is there any way to make netty (or vertx) delete such tmp files?

Answer (score 0):

Netty itself will not create such files, so it will either be vertx ( I am not aware vertx is doing this either) or something else.

Answer (score 0):

these files are generated by **io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.DiskAttribute.java**, to avoid generating these files, set "**useDisk**" to false in **DefaultHttpDataFactory.java** when you init your param decoder